# Go: test internal functions

Tags: testing, go, internal

Suppose I have a type `MyType` with a private method `(mt *MyType) private()` in a package `mypackage`.
I also have a directory `tests`, where I want to store tests for my package. This is how `tests/mypackage_test.go` looks like:

```
package mypackage_test

import (
    "testing"
    "myproj/mypackage"
)

func TestPrivate(t *testing.T) {
    // Some test code
}
```

However, when I run `go test` I get the `cannot refer to unexported field or method my package.(*MyType)."".private)` error. I've googled a bit and found out that functions starting with lower case can not be seen outside their own package (and this seems to be true, 'cause upper case functions are freely callable from the tests).

I also read somewhere that adding `<...>_internal_test.go` to the test file could solve my problem like this (`tests/mypackage_internal_test.go`):

```
package mypackage

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestPrivate(t *testing.T) {

    mt := &MyType{}
    // Some test code
}
```

But with this I only get `undefined: MyType`. So, my question: how can I test internal/private methods?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why do you place your tests in a different package? The go testing mechanism uses `_test` as a suffix for test files so you can place tests in the same packages as the actual code, avoiding the problem you describe. Placing tests in a separate package is not idiomatic Go. Do not try to fight the Go conventions, it's not worth the effort and you are mostly going to lose the fight.

Comment: Go supports declaring a package suffixed "_test" in the same folder as the main package - see https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages "test files that declare a package with the suffix "_test" will be compiled as a separate package, and then linked and run with the main test binary".

That's specifically so that you can have tests inline with source without having to include them in the same package, which I'd argue is generally an antipattern because it tests internals vs exported API, and includes test methods in the exported API.

Comment: @George I don't know where you got the idea testing your internals is an anti-pattern, but you should never, *ever* take advice from that source again. Yes, testing your external API is important, but that says *nothing* about the importance of testing internals, which is critical to quickly isolating and fixing breakage when it inevitably happens.

Comment: For testing the package is recompiled into a separate binary with `_test.go` files, no need to worry about polluting the exported symbol namespace.
`'Go test' recompiles each package along with any files with names matching the file pattern "*_test.go". These additional files can contain test functions, benchmark functions, fuzz tests and example functions.`

Answer (score 3):

*Go insists that files in the same folder belong to the same package, that is except for `_test.go` files. Moving your test code out of the package allows you to write tests as though you were a real user of the package. You cannot fiddle around with the internals, instead you focus on the exposed interface and are always thinking about any noise that you might be adding to your API.*

And:

*If you do need to unit test some internals, create another file with `_internal_test.go` as the suffix. Internal tests will necessarily be more brittle than your interface tests — but they’re a great way to ensure internal components are behaving, and are especially useful if you do test-driven development.*

Source: https://medium.com/@matryer/5-simple-tips-and-tricks-for-writing-unit-tests-in-golang-619653f90742

There are different opinions on how you should struct you tests within a golang project and I suggest you to read the blog above.